# C++ to_string not a member of std on Dev C++

Tags: c++, c++11, dev-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int subtract(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1-num2;
}

int main() 
{
    cout << "Input the number to subtract from: ";
    int num1;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "\nInput the number to subtract from " + std::to_string(num1);
    int num2;
    cin >> num2;
}
```

No other posts have helped me at all. All of them just say you have to have C++11 enabled, but I already do.

[Error] 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'

Comment: Can you post the *exact* error message you're getting?

Comment: Yes, [Error] 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'

Comment: How are you compiling this? What are you compiling it with? Is it a real compiler, or something pretending to be one?

Comment: Dev-C++ should not be used anymore. It never fully supported C++11 and has been abandoned for years, I believe.

Comment: Why do people still use Dev-C++? Visual Studio Code is much better, and with a C++ extension integrates with the latest GCC 10 nicely.

Comment: clang, GCC and VCC (Visual Studio) are all great at supporting the various C++ standards. Other compilers aren't really worth using unless you're forced to.

Comment: In that case I'll use Visual studio code then, it's just that it has way worse performance on my laptop, it's kinda old.

Comment: Or use sublime text or notepad++ or even vim. They take a bit more work to set up, but will all get the job done.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is a bit of work to set up compared to Visual Studio Community which is a lot more integrated, but both can do the job. Visual Studio Code offers more flexibility in choice of compiler back-end.

Comment: @tadman true, but VS Community is Windows-only, whereas VS Code is cross-platform. I presume an OS like Ubuntu would run better on an old laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have passed flag `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` to the compiler. This should be set somewhere in the project options. Otherwise, compiler that is included with Dev-C++ might operate by default in the c++98 mode, which, obviously, doesn't have `std::to_string()`, i.e. that is correct for C++98, which you likely have without that option.